# settingcontent-ms file tag meaning

Tags: windows, winapi, windows-8, registry, controlpanel

Windows 8 has a feature: it can launch an application from the search panel (on the right side of the screen). It works like following:

- Developer registers his or her application following this [instruction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/hh127450%28v%3dvs.85%29). It is a bit legacy instruction, but the project I participate in uses this way to register its settings.
- At user logon Windows creates (if none exists) a special .xml file in `C:\User\<UserName>\AppData\Packages\windows.immersivecontrolpanel_cw5n1h2txyewy\LocalState\Indexed\Settings\en-US` with content shown below. This file has extension `settingscontent-ms`
- As soon as user clicked on this file, the system launches the specified application (actually explorer calls for it, as I discovered by ProcMon).

Xml file content:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<PCSettings>
    <SearchableContent xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Search/2013/SettingContent">
        <ApplicationInformation>
            <AppID>windows.immersivecontrolpanel_cw5n1h2txyewy!microsoft.windows.immersivecontrolpanel</AppID>
            <DeepLink>%Canonical name or application path%</DeepLink>
            <Icon>%App path%,-%Resource number%</Icon>
        </ApplicationInformation>
        <SettingIdentity>
            <PageID>%GUID as in instruction above%</PageID>
            <HostID>{7E0522FC-1AC4-41CA-AFD0-3610417A9C41}</HostID>
            <Condition>shcond://v1#RegkeyExists;0;Regkey;HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ControlPanel\NameSpace\%GUID as in instruction above%</Condition>
        </SettingIdentity>
        <SettingInformation>
            <Name>@%App path%,-%Resource number%</Name>
            <Description>@%App path%,-%Resource number%</Description>
            <HighKeywords>%App decription%</HighKeywords>
        </SettingInformation>
    </SearchableContent>
</PCSettings>
```

We can see node with the name `HostID`. Windows writes specified in code GUID to this node, but it breaks the ability of my application to work. If I try to execute my app through this "shortcut" by clicking on xml file or chosing my app in search panel, the system shows me a message: "Unspecified error".

When I manually change the `HostID` value to `{12B1697E-D3A0-4DBC-B568-CCF64A3F934D}`, it starts to wrk fine.

I looked through registry in order to find something about these two GUIDs, but I didn't find anything. Also I looked for the difference between registry values corresponding to my app and to another, but working, app and didn't find any significand differences too.

Also I tried to delete this file and login into the system under ProcMon, I caught some moments: explorer tries to open the file and fails with `ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`, explorer creates missing file, reads registry and writes something to created file, then it closes the file. But I didn't find anything interesting in between of these messages, that can help me to solve my problem.

I found out that registry key `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\%App GUID%\System.ApplicationName` contains exactly the same with `DeepLink` tag (it was the first error in my app - specified key was empty), but the proble with "wrong" `HostID` remains.

Does anyone know, what it is and how to make Windows to write the rigth GUID to this tag, or at least some useful info about this tag? I just can't imagine anything else to change, but I think, that I need to change something in corresponding to my app registry keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution: just put app's GUID (the same as in `PageID`) into DeepLink.
To do this, you need to write this GUID as string value to `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\%App GUID%\System.ApplicationName`.

That's the solution. However, I haven't found the meaning of `HostID` tag :(